# How to generate different SHA1 fingerprint in android studio

Tags: android, sha1, fingerprint

I like to know that, if can we generate various SHA1 fingerprint for the same system using or without using android studio. If anyone knows please tell me clearly

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure I understood. You can generate as many as you want. What is the question here? What is the goal?

Comment: Actually i created SHA1 fingerprint for appindexing assetlinks.json concept and i gave the SHA1 key in that file. Now  i look the SHA1 fingerprint key from the same system but the present is different from the  assetlinks.json file .. So now i am in confuse how to get the old key from my system

Answer (score 0):

SHA1 fingerprint is generated by

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\keytool.exe
```

not by Android Studio

you use the

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\keytool.exe"-exportcert -list -v -alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

then you provide the password to access your keystore file (.jks file).

it will generate a SHA1 that you can copy for instance to `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/zzzzzzzz/settings/general/android:com.xxxxx.yyyyy`

which is the web link to your App Firebase Settings.